# Dropbox Saver API url as base64 works when upload 1 file when upload multiple i got error?

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

i used "https://www.dropbox.com/developers/saver" Api and based on document to upload multiple file i send list of base64 string to Dropbox, but i got an error fail to upload, when select only one file it uploaded successfully!

and here sample code

```
 var options ={files:[]};
      for (var i=0;i< attachments.length; i++) {
        var item = attachments[i];
        var file = {
          url: 'data&colon;application/pdf;base64,'+ item.fileByte
          filename: item.name
        };
        options.files.push(file);
      }

var button = window.Dropbox.createSaveButton(options);
document.getElementById("pdfcontainer").appendChild(button);
```

Comment: [ Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Dropbox-Saver-API-url-as-base64-works-when-upload-1-file-when/m-p/400705#M21931 ]

Comment: @Greg but for single file it works, i don't like to make full application since just uploading files needed

Comment: @msm2020 Given that's it's not officially supported, I can't say why it might work for one but not multiple files, but in any case, we don't recommend relying on it as it may break even for one file.